# How can I get public files path in javascript files?

Tags: 7, javascript, files

I want to display files present in the public folder(sites/default/files). So in the module file when I click on a link it will call to js function, How can I get all file names which are present in the public folder in js file.

Comment: Why don't you just point to that exactly file instead of trying to get all the files present in that folder?

Comment: Means, full path to that files.? How can I hyperlink to the path while displaying the file names. I am displaying something like this,  $data .= '<div class = "public-file-names" >' ."--". $filenames .'<br></div>'; so how can i  give full path in backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you are storing all your files, to use the base url of your site you need to do this:

```
$base_url."/sites/default/files/xxx.jpg"
```

If your files are inside some theme:

```
$base_url."/".drupal_get_path('theme', 'name_theme')."/images/xxx.png
```

If you are using files with **public://**, use this:

```
$uri = $your_file_name; // Example "public://xxx"
$path= file_create_url($uri);
```

I hope it works in your case

Comment: Thank you, It works fine. your solution will display the full content of the file in browser, but how can I get the popup asking that save file or open file??

Comment: No problem, if you are using HTML5 on your site you can use this tag: <a href="/xxx.pdf" download target="_blank">

Comment: This will open in new tab, but I want to show the popup before displaying the file content. Just now i have asked question please refer this url: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210829/how-to-show-popup-for-save-or-view-the-file

Comment: you can't really accomplish this, you can force the tag "a" to do either one way or another, but not both, because it depends on the plugins and components of the user that has installed in his computer

Comment: I thinks that depends upon file extension. Because for .csv files it will show popup, nut for .xml,.txt it will not show the popup. So you know how can show that popup to here also?